# Obexctl does not properly initialise and freezes

Tags: bluetooth, freeze

I am encountering an issue when executing the "obexctl" command in Ubuntu terminal.

Please refer to this article: https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/bluez/reference/sending-files

So at times when I am executing "obexctl" it shows

```
$ obexctl
[NEW] Client /org/bluez/obex
[obex]#
```

This means that the OBEX client has been properly initialised and I am able to properly use it as expected.

However, other times this would be the result

```
$ obexctl
[obex]#
```

Basically there is no [NEW] Client and I am **unable** to type any letters into the prompt. The cursor seems to keep flashing which means the terminal is not frozen but when I am attempting to type, the letters do not appear.

Comment: I had the exact same issue (linux Mint 20.3).  I think it's one time you used "sudo" obexctl, and other time you didn't?